# How can I prevent off the screen the dragging of a p-dialog from PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dialog

I'm using p-dialog from PrimNG. With `[draggable]` enabled, I can prevent the modal from being dragged off-screen on the left and top using `[minX]` and `[minY]`.

Is there a way to prevent the modal from being dragged off-screen on the right and bottom?

I am using https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog in a pretty standard implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As '[minX]' is the minimum draggable coordinates to the left and '[minY]' is the minimum draggable coordinates to the top, set them to a large negative number i.e. `[minX]="-1000" [minY]="-1000"` . In this way you will be able to drag the dialog much more to the left and top.

Comment: I am trying to prevent the p-dialog from going off on the right and bottom I want the behavior to prevent the p-dialog from going off screen at all.

Answer (score 0):

This commit fixed your problem:
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/commit/c47b22fe3e850ca95ab36e9d99f9bf900832a682?branch=c47b22fe3e850ca95ab36e9d99f9bf900832a682&diff=split

But as I discovered, Edge is having some trouble with it when you sroll the page and then you open the modal

Comment: yup only a year after my question and 2 since I was working on the project.

Comment: Nice to know. Do you've also the problem under the Edge browser?

Answer (score 0):

maybe will be useful for someone.

```html
  <ConfirmDialog
        visible={visibleState}
        onHide={() => handleCloseModal()}
        accept={accept}
        reject={reject}
        draggable={false} // just add draggable - false
      />
```